# Run function until successful

Tags: c#

I have an installation that runs post checks. What I'm looking to do is call the Function

```
private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
    }
    else
    {
        StartApacheServer();
    }
    if(ApacheRunning() == false)
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";
    }
    else
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is is until `ApacheRunning() == true` I want it to keep running this function. Is this something possible in C#?

Comment: `ServiceController` has a built in [`WaitForStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to start the Apache service.

Comment: Thank you! What I had just done was inside of `if(ApacheRunning() == false) { ApacheTest(); }` but I have a feeling `WaitForStatus` may be the preferred way to run this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
    }
    else
    {
        StartApacheServer();
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";
    while(ApacheRunning() == false)
    {
       Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";        
}
```

Here I used [`Task.Delay(1000)`](http://Task.Delay(1000);) to check state of server each seconds.

Comment: Might want to do a `Task.Delay`.

Comment: I've used a combination of your method and Sahuagin's now I'm trying to decide who I'm going to post as the answer I've selected. My main thing with his, was I liked his exit method on failing to find the actual file.

Comment: Very true. Wish there was a way to thank both parties.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: @MorganGreen I will explain why this way is more proper than Sahuagin's one. His: will check server state many many times but with Task.Delay you can do it only each seconds( or less if you need), it will be more performance I think

Comment: Thanks! One of the main factors on what I chose was the `Task.Delay` That right there while I had never heard of it I started looking into it after it was brought up and I saw it as the most effective way rather than checking every .1 seconds or so.

Comment: Am I missing something? `Task.Delay()` should return a `Task` instance that, unless `await`ed, doesn't do anything here.

Comment: You must await the returned Task.Delay() for it to do anything, you now have effectively a empty while loop that is going to use 100% of a cpu core. A `Thread.Sleep(1000)` would make more sense if you could not make the function async.

Comment: Well, or `Task.Delay(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but then again `Thread.Sleep(...)` is much easier on the eyes and doesn't spam out new `Task` instances.

Comment: this will spin forever or show "apache started" if the apache check fails, neither of which is desirable. in fact the user will never even see the "apache not found" message.

Comment: When I ran it earlier it gave me the apache not found when I did an intentional fail, but I also used return true;

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop, but also some other changes.

```
private void ApacheTest() {
   if (!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH)) {
      amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
      return;
   }

   amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";       
   StartApacheServer();

   while (ApacheRunning() == false) {
      // spin
   }

   amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
}
```

You should exit the function if "Apache is not found", rather than continue (`return` statement).

Say "Apache is starting" as soon as possible, and no need to set it over and over.

Comment: What's the purpose of the return in the error exit? Still new to C#, so I hate not knowing what I'm doing at all, but I'm noticing a lot of practices I use in PHP won't work in C#.

Comment: @MorganGreen Leaves the function. If you determine that a required condition has not been met such that the server cannot be started in the first place, then you need to quit. Another possibility is throwing an exception, or returning a success/fail value. (Note that without the return statement, the function will either infinitely loop, or else print "Apache Started" if apache is not found, neither of which are good.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've upvoted your answer, but because I used more out of Megatrons I've selected his as the best answer! Would have combined and gave credit to both if I could have!

Answer (score 1):

This might work, but it may also freeze your UI (window).

```
private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
    }
    else
    {
        StartApacheServer();
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";

    while(ApacheRunning() == false)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
}
```

If that happens, you may try something like this:

```
private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
        return;
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while(ApacheRunning() == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // nicked from [the MSDN forums][1]
}
```

That way, the function will exit and "fire and forget" the task of waiting and updating the text.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget return statement inside the if block!

```
private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        StartApacheServer();
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";

    while(ApacheRunning() == false)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `System.Thread.Sleep(5)` cause an unresponsive control panel?

Comment: Yes Morgan. Both Task.Delay and Thread.Sleep will cause unresponsive UI without using async/await. I added a new answer about this.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want your form not to be locked, then you can use "async/await" functionality with "Task.Delay".

```
async private void ApacheTest()
{
    if(!File.Exists(HTTPD_PATH))
    {
        amountdl.Text = "Apache Not Found! Installation Corrupt!";
        return;
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Is Starting";
    StartApacheServer();

    while(ApacheRunning() == false)
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }

    amountdl.Text = "Apache Started";
}
```

Comment: `async void` is basically a highway to hell; `async Task` would be the correct way to do it in almost all cases (regardless of how the user is going to use it in the end.)